# How to optimize detail page reset button in C# MAUI?

Tags: c#, maui

I've implemented a Reset button on a Detail page in C# MAUI and it works, but I can't figure out why I need to be so explicit in the way I capture the initial data to perform the reset, when requested.

Here's my code:

Simple 3 field data model:

```
public class MyDataModel
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int my_id { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
}
```

Reset button - when clicked, the form refills with the initial data perfectly using this:

```
private void Reset_Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindingContext = model = InitialData;
}
```

Detail page constructor - here's where my question is...

```
private MyDataModel model;

MyDataModel InitialData = new MyDataModel();

public DetailPageMyDataModel MyData)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = model = MyData;

    InitialData = MyData;   // Here's what I'd like to do, but it doesn't reset the fields

    InitialData.first_name = MyData.first_name;   // Instead, I have to use these two lines
    InitialData.last_name = MyData.last_name;     // Why???
}
```

Why isn't `InitialData = MyData` alone setting my `InitialData` and giving me the ability to reset my form later?

Unfortunately, it doesn't do anything - the reset doesn't work if I only use that line.

So, instead, I have to use the two lines below to get my reset button to work.  (Note: I can remove `InitialData = MyData` line as long as I include the other two.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: `InitialData = MyData` just points `InitialData` at the **same data** that `MyData` points to.  Both are referencing the same copy of the data, and a change to one will change both.

Comment: @Jason I'm sure you're right, but then why doesn't  ```BindingContext = model = InitialData``` reset by data?  Instead, I have to include the two other lines like this: ```InitialData.first_name = MyData.first_name```.

Comment: Maybe setting BindingContext to the same object again doesn't trigger BIndingContextChanged event. Try setting to `null` before setting again.

Comment: I believe when you assign `MyData` to `InitialData`, then `InitialData` is effectively the same object that `BindingContext` is pointing to. Changing the field in the form will also change `MyData` as well as `InitialData`. So when you reset, nothing actually happened since you are assigning the same object again to `BindingContext` .

Answer (score 1):

From document [BindableObject.BindingContextChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindableobject.bindingcontextchanged?view=xamarin-forms), we can find that :

> event `BindingContextChanged` Raised whenever the BindingContext property changes.

Though it is a xamrin form document, it also applies to MAUI.

If we change the value of the properties of the current `BindingContext`, event `BindingContextChanged` will be triggered.

But if you use code `InitialData = MyData;`, the `InitialData` will refer to another  instance that `MyData` point to. That is to say, `InitialData` will no longer point to the previous object and memory space. Therefore, in this case, the `BindingContextChanged` event of the current page's `BindingContext` object will no longer be fired.

> ```
> InitialData.first_name = MyData.first_name;   // Instead, I have to use these two lines
> InitialData.last_name = MyData.last_name;     // Why???
> ```

Conversely, if you use above code, you are not changing the object pointed to by the `BindingContext` of the current page, you are only changing the value of the property of this object.In this case, event `BindingContextChanged` will raise.

Comment: This is interesting information, but I'm still not clear how to implement the reset form function in an elegant way. Explicitly listing all my fields in the constructor works, but it could cause problems when/if my data model changes.

Comment: `but it could cause problems when/if my data model changes`  Can you elaborate on what went wrong? And what is the problem?

Comment: If I explicitly list every property, like this '''InitialData.first_name = MyData.first_name''', then whenever I add/delete fields (like add middle_name) then I need to make sure I add this to my list of Initial Data = MyData items.

Comment: `then whenever I add/delete fields (like add middle_name) then I need to make sure I add this to my list of Initial Data = MyData items.`   Sorry,I still don't quite understand your needs by above words.  For MVVM, if we change the value of the properties of our viewmodel, then UI will refresh automatically.